# Is there any alternative to UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() in macOS programming?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-graphics

i am using below code to create images from UILabel class and storing them in document directory. i want to achieve same thing in macOS but did not find anything also i have never programmed in macOS App environment. in macOS app i tried taking screenshot of portion using CGDisplayCreateImage() but result were not as expected. so what i want to do is create label and store it as image in local storage in macOS application.

```
class func imageWith(name: String?) {
    //sizes = [Int]
    sizes.forEach { (value) in
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: value, height: value)
        let nameLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
        nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = .black
        nameLabel.textColor = .white
        var fontSize = 25
        if value == 120 {
            fontSize = 50
        } else if value == 180 {
            fontSize = 60
        }
        nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(fontSize))
        nameLabel.text = String(name?.prefix(2) ?? "Aa")

        //logic i wanted to port to macos
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
        if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            nameLabel.layer.render(in: currentContext)
            let nameImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

            //function which will save images to documents directory
            saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: nameImage, name: name ?? "dummy", value: value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question, post your attempt and the issues you are facing.

Comment: Please post the macOS code that you tried and describe more clearly what results you got that were "not as expected".

Answer (score 0):

Any NSView subclass can be rendered as an image using `.dataWithPDF(inside:)`. Try this:

```
let dataOfView = nameLabel.dataWithPDF(inside: nameLabel.bounds)
let imageOfView = NSImage(data: dataOfView)
```